# Get a Single value of Li randomly and print it in <h1> tag

Tags: javascript, html-lists

I have a list of values in a ul element in HTML and using javascript, I want to output in h1 a random value out of that list. I already have a script but its inputting the ID of that LI instead of the value.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="quotes-list">
<ul>
    <li id="One">One</li>
    <li id="Two">Two</li>
    <li id="Three">Three</li>
    <li id="Four">Four</li>
    <li id="Five">Five</li>
</ul>
</div>​

<h1 id="quoted"></h1>
```

and here's my javascript:

```
var lis = document.getElementById("quotes-list").getElementsByTagName("li");
var countThis = Math.floor(Math.random() * lis.length);

var carToon = (lis[countThis].id);

var textElement = document.getElementById("quoted");
textElement.innerHTML = carToon;
```

As I've said, this is working but it's outputting the id of the LI.

I've tried playing around with the

```
var carToon = (lis[countThis].id);
```

putting lis[countThis].**text** but the output would be "**UNDEFINED**"

What could be replace on my code so that I can output in H1 a random Value out of my ul list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
var carToon = (lis[countThis].id);
```

to

```
var carToon = (lis[countThis].innerHTML);
```